# Why can't my jQuery's .data() usage store my object in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, garbage-collection, overlay

I'm trying to use jQuery's `.data()` method to store an overlay object to the target element, however every time I run this code the target element doesn't store any overlay. Here is my code:

```
var helper = {  // ...      
overlay: function ($target_element, zIndex) {
        var target_dimension = [$target_element.width(), $target_element.height()];
        var target_offset = $target_element.offset();
        var $screen = $("<div class='overlay'></div>")
                        .css({
                          "width": target_dimension[0],
                          "height": target_dimension[1],
                          "background-color": "#554A4A",
                          "opacity": 0.8,
                          "zIndex": zIndex,
                          "position": "absolute",
                          "top": target_offset.top,
                          "left": target_offset.left
                        });
        $target_element.append($screen);
        $target_element.data('overlayobj', $screen); // Here is where my confusion is.
        return $screen;
      },
// ...
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    helper.overlay($('div#test:last'), 1000);
    $('div#test').data('overlayobj'); // I expected to get back the overlay object, but always got an empty {} here.
});
```

Comment: What makes you think it isn't storing it? There's nothing above suggesting that. Your best bet is to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: seems many divs with same ids.....;)

Comment: @ TJ., That's easy to show the problem, it always returns an empty {}, instead of an overlay <div> object. How to make a Stack Snippets? I'm still familiarizing myself with this interface, sorry.

Comment: @ jai: No there is only one <div> with an id of #test.

Comment: @JinghuiNiu so why adding a pseudoselector `:last`?

Comment: @JinghuiNiu you can use `JSON.stringify($screen)` when you set it and when you get it. and you have a return statement so store it in a var.